# Why does std::vector::emplace call destructor without any copy constructor called?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, stdvector

I am storing objects inside a `std::vector`, and I want to avoid calling destructor as much as possible.
I replaced copy constructor and assignments by move ones:

```
class Object
{
    Object(const Object&) = delete;
    Object(Object&&);
    Object& operator=(const Object&) = delete;
    Object& operator=(Object&&);
    [...]
};
```

I am initializing it like this:

```
std::vector<Object>   container;

container.reserve(42) // Reserve a lot in order to be sure it won't be a problem
```

Then, I add two elements with [emplace_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) (the constructor takes one `int` parameter):

```
container.emplace_back(1);
container.emplace_back(3);
```

Until there, everything is fine. But then I want to insert an element before the last one with [emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/):

```
auto it = container.end();

it--; // Last position.
it--; // Before last position.
container.emplace(it, 2);
```

But here a destructor is called.

I tried to locate why with Valgrind, it appears `emplace` function calls `_M_insert_aux` that call my destructor.

How could I avoid that?

Comment: How exactly do you propose to do this without calling the destructor at least once?

Comment: `emplace` is different with `emplace_back`. `emplace_back` just construct a new element, `emplace` has to deal with the element already constructed at the specified position.

Comment: @T.C. This is precisely my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid that. This is simply how a `vector` works. It's a contiguous array. The only way you can insert a new element into a contiguous array is to *move* the old elements down. That means using move assignment to move them into their new positions.

So if you have the following vector, and their contents:

```
[5][12][16]
```

If you insert after the second element, then at some point you have this:

```
[5][12][*][16]
```

Where "*" is the value of a moved-from element.

Then comes the `emplace`. `emplace` explicitly will construct the value in place; that's what its for. However, there is already a live object in the 3rd element: the moved-from value.

Therefore, this object must be *destroyed* before the new object can be constructed in its place. Hence the destructor must be called.

If you used `insert` rather than `emplace`, then you would still have a destructor be called. But that would be the destructor of the object you pass to the `insert` function.

So there's going to be an "extra" destructor called *somewhere*.

But really, you shouldn't be worried about the number of destructor calls. Focus on absolute costs. Generally speaking, if you have a move-only type, the destructor for a moved-from value will be cheap.

Comment: My object allocate an element with `new[]` on construction, and destroy it with `delete[]` on destruction. As heap allocation may be heavy, I wondered how to avoid it as much as possible. But maybe too much.

Comment: That's what a move is for.  Your class should pass ownership of your `new[]`ed array from the moved-from object to the moved-to object.  That eliminates the need to `delete[]` the array in the destructor of the moved-from object, and the need to `new[]` a new array in your moved-to object.

Comment: @MilesBudnek So I just need to set the pointer of the original object to `nullptr` in order to not delete it... Thanks for the help.